# Combining multiple lists of dictionaries together matching on a specific key

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following datasets and I'm looking to combine them together, with specific keys being edid or nsid, depending on the dataset.  In each dataset, there could be two or more dictionaries in each list, but each dataset with match depending on the edid or nsid. I'm using Python 3.9.2.

**Components**

```
components = {
    "endpoints": [
        {
            "edid": "b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29",
            "nsid": "ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7",
            "name": "client",
        },
        {
            "edid": "c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18",
            "nsid": "ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4",
            "name": "server",
        },
    ]
}
```

**Resources**

```
resources = {
    "resources": [
        {
            "nsid": "ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7",
            "resources": {"cpu": "8", "memory": "2000", "storage": "50"},
        },
        {
            "nsid": "ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4",
            "resources": {"cpu": "16", "memory": "4000", "storage": "150"},
        },
    ]
}
```

**Elements**

```
elements = {
    "locations": [
        {
            "edid": "b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29",
            "pid": "beba5457-cc98-4e60-b400-c938c75022ef",
            "ip": "10.100.19.72",
        },
        {
            "edid": "c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18",
            "pid": "16a9c3ec-8e88-4456-9679-cc6687d4d52d",
            "ip": "10.10.19.44",
        },
    ]
}
```

**Conns**

```
conns = {
    "conns": [
        {
            "edid": "b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29",
            "switch": 20,
            "port": 8,
            "vlan": 101,
        },
        {
            "edid": "c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18",
            "switch": 14,
            "port": 12,
            "vlan": 105,
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I combine these datasets together to create the following:

**Desired Output**

```
[
    {
        "edid": "b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29",
        "nsid": "ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7",
        "name": "client",
        "vlan": "101",
        "switch": "20",
        "port": "8",
        "cpu": "8", 
        "memory": "2000", 
        "storage": "50",
        "pid": "beba5457-cc98-4e60-b400-c938c75022ef",
        "ip": "10.100.19.72",
    },
    {
        "edid": "c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18",
        "nsid": "ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4",
        "name": "server",
        "vlan": "105",
        "switch": "14",
        "port": "12",
        "cpu": "16", 
        "memory": "4000", 
        "storage": "150",
        "pid": "16a9c3ec-8e88-4456-9679-cc6687d4d52d",
        "ip": "10.10.19.44",
    },
]
```

Comment: do you want it to be `"switch_id"`, and `"switch_port"` on the first dict and `"switch"` `"port"` on the second, or was that a typo?

Comment: Hi David, oops sorry, yes it should be switch, port on both.  I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

**First I'll merge all datasets**

```
{'endpoints': [{'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
                'nsid': 'ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7',
                'name': 'client'},
               {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
                'nsid': 'ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4',
                'name': 'server'}],
 'resources': [{'nsid': 'ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7',
                'resources': {'cpu': '8', 'memory': '2000', 'storage': '50'}},
               {'nsid': 'ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4',
                'resources': {'cpu': '16',
                              'memory': '4000',
                              'storage': '150'}}],
 'locations': [{'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
                'pid': 'beba5457-cc98-4e60-b400-c938c75022ef',
                'ip': '10.100.19.72'},
               {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
                'pid': '16a9c3ec-8e88-4456-9679-cc6687d4d52d',
                'ip': '10.10.19.44'}],
 'conns': [{'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
            'switch': 20,
            'port': 8,
            'vlan': 101},
           {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
            'switch': 14,
            'port': 12,
            'vlan': 105}]}
```

**Then I'll get the `dict` inside every item and add them to a list**

```
[{'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
   'nsid': 'ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7',
   'name': 'client'},
  {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
   'nsid': 'ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4',
   'name': 'server'},
  {'nsid': 'ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7',
   'resources': {'cpu': '8', 'memory': '2000', 'storage': '50'}},
  {'nsid': 'ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4',
   'resources': {'cpu': '16', 'memory': '4000', 'storage': '150'}},
  {'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
   'pid': 'beba5457-cc98-4e60-b400-c938c75022ef',
   'ip': '10.100.19.72'},
  {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
   'pid': '16a9c3ec-8e88-4456-9679-cc6687d4d52d',
   'ip': '10.10.19.44'},
  {'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
   'switch': 20,
   'port': 8,
   'vlan': 101},
  {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
   'switch': 14,
   'port': 12,
   'vlan': 105}]
```

**Then I'll make groups inside that list based on the number of dictionaries inside the first dataset** (in this step I'm assuming every dataset has the same amount of dictionaries)

```
[[{'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
   'nsid': 'ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7',
   'name': 'client'},
  {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
   'nsid': 'ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4',
   'name': 'server'}],
 [{'nsid': 'ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7',
   'resources': {'cpu': '8', 'memory': '2000', 'storage': '50'}},
  {'nsid': 'ae5c86c2-ab4c-4df0-891e-54c7b955c4b4',
   'resources': {'cpu': '16', 'memory': '4000', 'storage': '150'}}],
 [{'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
   'pid': 'beba5457-cc98-4e60-b400-c938c75022ef',
   'ip': '10.100.19.72'},
  {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
   'pid': '16a9c3ec-8e88-4456-9679-cc6687d4d52d',
   'ip': '10.10.19.44'}],
 [{'edid': 'b41e844c-67ec-4d13-8887-3ae155320f29',
   'switch': 20,
   'port': 8,
   'vlan': 101},
  {'edid': 'c0e89321-d7ea-479f-aa5e-519b053acf18',
   'switch': 14,
   'port': 12,
   'vlan': 105}]]
```

After that I just have to `zip` the grouped list and merge every item of that `zip` object together.

All of that can be achieved by using an `update` function inside a `reduce` function . The result should look something like this:

```
from functools import reduce

data = [endpoints, resources, locations, conns]


def merge_dict(x: dict, y: dict):
    z = dict()
    for k, v in y.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            z.update(v)
            continue
        z[k] = v
    x.update(z)
    return x


def merge_list(x: list, y: list):
    x.extend(y)
    return x


def subdivide_list(ls: list, groupsize: int):
    return list(map(lambda x: ls[min(x*groupsize, len(ls)-1):min((x+1)*groupsize, len(ls))], range(len(ls)//groupsize)))


endpoint_count = len(list(data[0].values())[0])
output = list(map(lambda x: reduce(merge_dict, x), zip(*subdivide_list(reduce(merge_list, reduce(merge_dict, data).values()), endpoint_count))))
```